# Create instance with random string

Tags: c#

I'm working on a text adventure game but I have some difficulties with the combat system since I want random enemies. Which gets a string received of the enemy name from the

```
string enemyName = map.GetLocation().GetEnemyName();
```

But how do I go from this string to instance because this does not work:

```
Monster Monster = new enemyName(6);
```

Is there any other great way to fix this?

This is my current code:

program.cs

```
static void Combat(ref Map map, ref List<string> menuItems, ref Inventory Inventory, ref Player Player)
        {
        int choice;
        Player.SetInCombat(true);
        bool inCombat = Player.GetInCombat();

        string enemyName = map.GetLocation().GetEnemyName();

        Console.WriteLine(enemyName);

        Monster Monster = new Skeleton(6);

        //Player
        int hpPlayer = Player.GetHealth();
        int dpPlayer = Convert.ToInt32(Player.GetDefence());
        int attackPlayer = Player.GetAttackPoints();

        bool run = false;

        //Enemy
        string name = Monster.GetName();
        int hpEnemy = Monster.GetHealth();
        int dpEnemy = Monster.GetDefence();
        int enemyLevel = Monster.GetLevel();
        int attackEnemy = Monster.GetAttack();
            string attackName = Monster.GetAttackName();
}
```

Monster.cs

```
abstract class Monster
    {
        protected int level;
        protected string name;
        protected string attackName;
        protected int maxHealth;
        protected int health;
        protected int attack;
        protected int defence;
        protected int healthMultiplier;
        protected int attackMultiplier;
        protected int defenceMultiplier;

        public Monster(int level)
        {
            this.level = level;
        }

        public string GetName()
        {
            return name;
        }

        public string GetAttackName()
        {
            return attackName;
        }

        public int GetMaxHealth()
        {
            return maxHealth;
        }

        public int GetHealth()
        {
            return health;
        }

        public int GetAttack()
        {
            return attack;
        }

        public int GetDefence()
        {
            return defence;
        }

        public abstract void TakeHit(int damage, ref Player Player);

        public int GetLevel()
        {
            return level;
        }
    }
```

Here is 1 of the 4 different kind of enemies:

Skeleton.cs

```
class Skeleton : Monster
    {
        public Skeleton(int level)
            : base(level)
        {
            //Monster stats

            name = "Skeleton";
            attackName = "Bone_thrower";
            healthMultiplier = 2;
            attackMultiplier = 1;
            defenceMultiplier = 25;

            maxHealth = (level * healthMultiplier);
            health = maxHealth;
            attack = (level / attackMultiplier);
            defence = (level / defenceMultiplier);
        }

        public override void TakeHit(int damage, ref Player Player)
        {
            if (health - damage <= 0)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} took {1} points of damage.", name, damage);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.WriteLine("Press any keys to continue...");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Player.SetInCombat(false);
            }
            else
            {
                health -= damage;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} took {1} points of damage.", name, damage);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should probably have a `map.GetLocation().GetEnemy();` that returns a `Monster` instead of `map.GetLocation().GetEnemyName();`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Activator_CreateInstance_System_String_System_String_

Comment: You could put your instances of monsters in a `List<Monster>` and then search them by name with LINQ: `Monster monster = monsterList.Where(m => m.name == enemyName).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: You really should provide a **minimal example** of what you need. This is way too much code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common pattern used in cases like yours is a factory method. Instead of the `GetEnemyName` method you can create a method `GetEnemy`. There are different ways to create enemies from a random number. The simplest way, which works well when you only have a few monster classes, would be a `switch` statement:

```
Random numberGenerator = new Random();

public Monster GetEnemy(int level) {
    const int numberOfEnemies = 2; //Set appropriate value
    int enemyIndex = numberGenerator.Next(numberOfEnemies);

    switch (enemyIndex) {
        case 0:
            return new Skeleton(level);
        case 1:
            return new OtherMonsterType(level);
        default:
            //Should never be called, serves as a safeguard and to make the code compile
            throw new NotSupportedException() 
    }
}
```

In case you have more monster types that you want to manage more dynamically (eg. add new monster types on higher levels), you can use a list of methods that will create the monsters (which can be expressed in a simple way with lambda expressions):

```
Random numberGenerator = new Random();
List<Func<int, Monster>> monsterCreators = new List<Func<int, Monster>> {
    level => new Skeleton(level),
    level => new OtherMonsterType(level),
    //...
}

public Monster GetEnemy(int level) {
    int enemyIndex = numberGenerator.Next(monsterCreators.Count);    
    return monsterCreators[enemyIndex](level);
}
```